# Xamarin ios - CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo doesnt return the correct BSSID

Tags: ios, xamarin, wifi, bssid

I have the following code to get the current WIFI's bssid :

```
var status = CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("en0", out dict);

if (status == StatusCode.NoKey)
{
       return null;
}
var bssid = dict[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeyBSSID];
var ssid = dict[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID];
```

But when I examine the bssid, I notice that one of the eight segments in the mac address has a different value that the actual bssid. For e.g. if the bssid of the wifi router is b0:34:f6:23:a1:33, The above code returns b0:b0:f6:23:a1:33 which is changed in the second segment.

How would one go about getting the correct bssid?